# randomized quick sort [crashes on some inputs]

Tags: c++, quicksort

**I removed the codes because it's homework. If you actually needs the help, you can either look at the discussion I had with George B (below), or PM me.**

---

Hi guys. This is a homework assignment. I have tested it against other sorting algorithms, and Q.S. is the only one that is crashing on some random inputs.

The program is quit long (with other stuff), but input is randomly generated....

I spent a few hours tracing the codes and still couldn't figure out any error.... 
Q.S. is probably very easy for the professionals, so I hope to receive advices on this implementation....

Any input is appreciated!

---

**Q: What is "random"?**

A: A portion of generation is included.

```
void randomArray(unsigned long*& A, unsigned long size)
{
 //Note that RAND_MAX is a little small for some compilers (2^16-1).
 //In order to test our algorithms on large arrays without huge
 //numbers of duplicates, we'll set the high-order and low-order
 //parts of the return value with two random values.
 A = new unsigned long[size];
 for(unsigned long i=0; i<size; i++)
  A[i] = (rand()<<16) | (rand());

 //Another note:  initially, if you want to test your program out with smaller
 //arrays and small numbers, just reduce A[i] mod k for some small value k as in the following:
 //A[i] = rand() % 16;
 //this may help you debug at first.
}
```

**Q: What kind of error?**

Well, I am not getting compilation error. Without Q.S., I can ran other four sorting algorithm without problems (I can continuously running the sorting). When Q.S is activated, after running the program one or two or three times, or even at the first time of running, the program ends (I am using Eclipse, so the consoles ends).

> enter the number of elements, or a
>   negative number to quit: 5 {some
>   arrays}
>
> selection sort took 0 seconds. merge
>   sort took 0 seconds. quick sort took 0
>   seconds. heap sort took 0 seconds.
>   bucket sort took 0 seconds. {output of
>   5 sorted arrays}
>
> enter the number of elements, or a
>   negative number to quit: 6 {some
>   arrays}
>
> selection sort took 0 seconds. merge
>   sort took 0 seconds. quick sort took 0
>   seconds. heap sort took 0 seconds.
>   bucket sort took 0 seconds.
>
> {output of 5 sorted arrays}
>
> enter the number of elements, or a
>   negative number to quit: 8 {arrays}
>   --- console ends---

Again, the problem is that it crashes quite often, so this suggests that there is a high possibility of access violation,,, but doing 10+ tracings I don't see the problem.... (maybe I overloaded my brain stack -*_*- )

Thanks.

Comment: The words "random" and "sort" used together are a bit confusing.

Comment: Could you give us what the errors are?

Comment: hi, yes. i edited my post with the answers, and the full program... i hope this helps with the debugging... thanks.... i am still working on the tracing... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

```
q is unsigned (the result of the partition function)
so, q-1 is also unsigned
what if q is zero?
```

(It is homework so you have to figure it out I guess :) )

Comment: first, thank you for the hint!. it's true... when i was doing this QS, one of my previous implementations recognized that problem too. thanks. but i forgot to change it just for now...... the problem is, however, Partition uses unsigned long in the interface, even if i explicitly int... the program still crashes...

Comment: int q = Partition(A, p, r);
   quickSort(A, p, int(q - 1));
   quickSort(A, int(q + 1), r); 
can you provides a little insight how to deal with that?

Comment: oh actually -1 doesn't exists... i should added that as return immedlately...right?

Comment: What I did: changed unsigned long everywhere to long and it worked :) (OK I didn't test it exhaustively but I think it works). The problem is that if q is unsigned, if the index gets negative the value wraps around (-1 is then 2^32-1), which again leads to accessing memory you can't use -> segmentation fault.

Comment: thanks you , George. I know the fix. i added if(q > 0) to the first quickSort

Comment: yes chaning unsigned is cool. but when my professor tests it i would be wrong with the automated testing program. but yeah. your hint is really helpful. hahaha. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trace your algorithm with the array `{2,5,2}`. Obviously your program crashes as soon as there are duplicate numbers in your list. The first call of Partition will return `2` as the index of `r`. Thus, the second call of `quickSort(A,3,2)` will access memory locations not within array boundaries. Its always a good idea to do the boundary checks for arrays manually and generate understandable output to more easily trace and debug your program.

Comment: right. i am going to double check the conditions. thanks, Pirooz.